# SqlParameter calling a user defined function in an Insert Query

Tags: prepared-statement

Im trying to execute a scalar valued function in an insert query. Im using sql parameter collection but still stuck with it.

### Query

```
Insert into PackageProducts values (@id, @name, @prodId, @prodCode)
```

// I want to call a scalar valued function to get value for the @prodCode when this query excecutes

### Function

```
create function getProdCodeById(@id uniqueidentifier) returns varchar(15)
begin
declare @code varchar(15)
select @code=ProductCode from Products where ID=@id
return @code
end
```

### What I'm trying to do

```
//create command, connection etc.. after than

DbParameter param = createParameter() ; // returns an empty parameter
param.Name = "@prodCode";
param.Value = String.Format("getProdCodeById('{0}')", 5);
```

when I execute , it takes the parameter value as a string.. the function never gets executed. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a select statement for your function

```
SELECT [dbo].[getProdCodeById] (@id)
```

You can assign this to a variable before using it, as in

```
DECLARE @parameter varchar(15)
SET @parameter  = (SELECT [dbo].[getProdCodeById] (@id))
```

You can now use @parameter anywhere in your code

Comment: when I execute the function in sql server it works.. the issue however, when I specify the function call as a value to an sql parameter ( even with the select keyword ), final query considers it as just a string

Comment: Firstly, assign the function to a parameter, then you can use it as your parameter